# Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL) at random times while operating with app

Tags: flutter, dart, yandex-mapkit

I've got a screen with yandex map and sliding up panel with many input texts inside and while Im operating with it (e.g. typing text into textfields) app may crash with an SIGABRT signal but may not, it only occurs when I have my sliding up panel open.

Full code:

```
import 'package:bilbord/dbMethods.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:yandex_mapkit/yandex_mapkit.dart';
import 'package:sliding_up_panel/sliding_up_panel.dart';
import 'package:flutter_rating_bar/flutter_rating_bar.dart';
class ControlButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const ControlButton({
    Key? key,
    required this.onPressed,
    required this.title
  }) : super(key: key);

  final VoidCallback onPressed;
  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4),
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: onPressed,
        child: Text(title, textAlign: TextAlign.center),
      ),
    );
  }
}

abstract class MapPage extends StatelessWidget {


  const MapPage(this.title,);

  final String title;

}

class UserLayerPage extends MapPage {


  const UserLayerPage({required this.point}) : super('Карта');
  final Point point;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _UserLayerExample(position: point);
  }
}

class _UserLayerExample extends StatefulWidget {
  final Point position;

  const _UserLayerExample({Key? key, required this.position}): super(key: key);
  @override
  _UserLayerExampleState createState() => _UserLayerExampleState();
}

class _UserLayerExampleState extends State<_UserLayerExample> {

  TextEditingController firm = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController construction = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController demonstration = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController width = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController height = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController address = TextEditingController();
  int positionRating = -1;
  int colorRating = -1;
  int passabilityRating = -1;
  int typeRating = -1;
  bool active = true;
  CameraPosition? _point;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    firm.dispose();
    construction.dispose();
    demonstration.dispose();
    width.dispose();
    height.dispose();
    address.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  late YandexMapController controller;

  Future<bool> get locationPermissionNotGranted async => !(await Permission.location.request().isGranted);
  void _showMessage(BuildContext context, Text text) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: text));
  }
  List<MapObject> mapObjects = [];
  Future<void> getUserPoint() async {
    await controller.toggleUserLayer(visible: true);
    print(await controller.getUserCameraPosition());
    final CameraPosition? _userPosition = await controller.getUserCameraPosition();
    await controller.moveCamera(
      CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
        CameraPosition(
          target: _userPosition!.target,
        ),
      ),
      animation: const MapAnimation(type: MapAnimationType.smooth, duration: 1.0)
    );
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
                child: Stack(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                  children: [
                    YandexMap(
                      onMapCreated: (YandexMapController yandexMapController) async {
                      controller = yandexMapController;
                      controller.moveCamera(
                          CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
                            CameraPosition(
                              target: widget.position,
                            ),
                          ),
                          animation: const MapAnimation(type: MapAnimationType.smooth, duration: 1.0)
                      );
                    },
                      mapObjects: mapObjects,
                    onUserLocationAdded: (UserLocationView view) async {
                      return view.copyWith(
                          pin: view.pin.copyWith(
                              icon: PlacemarkIcon.single(
                                  PlacemarkIconStyle(image: BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage('lib/assets/user.png'))
                              )
                          ),
                          arrow: view.arrow.copyWith(
                              icon: PlacemarkIcon.single(
                                  PlacemarkIconStyle(image: BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage('lib/assets/arrow.png'))
                              )
                          ),
                          accuracyCircle: view.accuracyCircle.copyWith(
                              fillColor: Colors.green.withOpacity(0.5)
                          )
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                    Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                        child: Visibility(
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                            children: [
                              FloatingActionButton(
                                heroTag: "showMe",
                                onPressed: () async {
                                  if (await locationPermissionNotGranted) {
                                    _showMessage(context, const Text('Необходимо разрешение на использование местоположения'));
                                    return;
                                  }
                                  await getUserPoint();
                                },
                                child: const Icon(Icons.gps_fixed_rounded),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(height: 10,),
                              FloatingActionButton(
                                heroTag: "putPlacemark",
                                onPressed: () async {
                                  _point = await controller.getCameraPosition();
                                  final placemark = Placemark(
                                    mapId: const MapObjectId('placemark'),
                                    point: _point!.target,
                                    );
                                  setState(() {
                                    //mapObjects.clear();
                                    mapObjects.add(placemark);
                                  });

                                  print(_point?.target.longitude);

                                  print(mapObjects.length);
                                },
                                child: const Icon(Icons.add),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(height: 10,),
                              const SizedBox(
                                height: 30,
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    const Center(
                      child: Icon(Icons.gps_fixed_rounded),
                    ),
                  ]
                )
            ),
            SlidingUpPanel(
              maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              minHeight: 40.0,
              parallaxEnabled: true,
              parallaxOffset: .1,
              header: SizedBox(
                child: Row(
                  children:const [
                    Icon(Icons.drag_handle)
                  ],
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                ),
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              ),

                  panelBuilder: (sc) => Padding(
                     padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0),
                      child: _InputPanel(sc),
                      ),
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(18.0),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(18.0)
              )
            )
          ]
      ),
    );
  }

Widget _InputPanel(ScrollController sc){
    return SingleChildScrollView(
        controller: sc,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 15,),
            TextField(
              controller: firm,
              decoration: inputDecoration("Фирма"),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10,),
            TextField(
              controller: construction,
              decoration: inputDecoration('Тип конструкции'),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10,),
            TextField(
              controller: demonstration,
              decoration: inputDecoration('Тип демонстрации'),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10,),
            Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: width,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    decoration: inputDecoration('Ширина'),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(width: 5,),
                Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: height,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    decoration: inputDecoration('Высота'),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10,),
            TextField(
              controller: address,
              decoration: inputDecoration('Адрес'),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10,),
            const Text("Оценка позиции: "),
            RatingBar.builder(
              initialRating: 0,
              minRating: 1,
              direction: Axis.horizontal,
              allowHalfRating: false,
              itemCount: 5,
              itemPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 6.0),
              itemBuilder: (context, _) => const Icon(
                Icons.star,
                color: Colors.amber,
              ),
              onRatingUpdate: (rating) {
                positionRating = rating.round();
              },
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10,),
            const Text("Оценка цвета: "),
            RatingBar.builder(
              initialRating: 0,
              minRating: 1,
              direction: Axis.horizontal,
              allowHalfRating: false,
              itemCount: 5,
              itemPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 6.0),
              itemBuilder: (context, _) => const Icon(
                Icons.star,
                color: Colors.amber,
              ),
              onRatingUpdate: (rating) {
                colorRating = rating.round();
              },
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10,),
            const Text("Оценка проходимости: "),
            RatingBar.builder(
              initialRating: 0,
              minRating: 1,
              direction: Axis.horizontal,
              allowHalfRating: false,
              itemCount: 5,
              itemPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 6.0),
              itemBuilder: (context, _) => const Icon(
                Icons.star,
                color: Colors.amber,
              ),
              onRatingUpdate: (rating) {
                passabilityRating = rating.round();
              },
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10,),
            const Text("Оценка типа баннера: "),
            RatingBar.builder(
              initialRating: 0,
              minRating: 1,
              direction: Axis.horizontal,
              allowHalfRating: false,
              itemCount: 5,
              itemPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 6.0),
              itemBuilder: (context, _) => const Icon(
                Icons.star,
                color: Colors.amber,
              ),
              onRatingUpdate: (rating) {
                typeRating = rating.round();
              },
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () => active ? () => _addBilbord(firm.text, construction.text, demonstration.text, width.text as double, height.text as double, address.text, positionRating, colorRating, passabilityRating, typeRating, _point!.target.longitude, _point!.target.latitude) : null,
                child: const Text("Добавить билборд")
            )
          ],
        ),
      );

}

Future<int> _addBilbord(String firm, String construction, String demonstration, double width, double height, String address, int positionRating, int colorRating, int passabilityRating, int typeRating, double lat, double long) async{
  active = false;
  var db = dbMethods();
  await db.getConnection().then((conn) async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    var result = await conn.query('INSERT INTO info '
        '(user, '
        'bannerfirm, '
        'construction_type,'
        'demonstration_type, '
        'lat,'
        'long,'
        'sizeX, '
        'sizeY, '
        'address, '
        'positionRate,'
        ' colorsRate,'
        ' passabilityRate,'
        ' typeRate'
        ') VALUES '
        '(1, "${firm}", "${construction}","${demonstration}",${lat}, ${long}, ${width}, ${height}, "${address}", ${positionRating},${colorRating}, ${passabilityRating}, ${typeRating});');
    active = true;
    print(result.insertId ?? -1);
    conn.close();
    return (result.insertId ?? -1);

  });

  active = true;
  return -1;
}

InputDecoration inputDecoration(String text) {
  return InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)
                ),
                hintText: text
  );
}
}
```

It often occurs when I click button too much but not necessarily. Seems like the problem is not inside database connection because even if I make onPressed method return null it keeps crashing randomly.

backtrace here:

```
F/libc    ( 1471): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 1471 (rd.plus.bilbord), pid 1471 (rd.plus.bilbord)
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/j6lteser/j6lte:10/QP1A.190711.020/J600FPUUACUH2:user/release-keys'
Revision: '2'
ABI: 'arm'
Timestamp: 2022-04-05 19:46:37+0300
pid: 1471, tid: 1471, name: rd.plus.bilbord  >>> com.bilbord.plus.bilbord <<<
uid: 10850
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
    r0  00000000  r1  000005bf  r2  00000006  r3  ffa0ca98
    r4  ffa0caac  r5  ffa0ca90  r6  000005bf  r7  0000016b
    r8  ffa0caa8  r9  ffa0ca98  r10 ffa0cac8  r11 ffa0cab8
    ip  000005bf  sp  ffa0ca68  lr  e8f6bc9f  pc  e8f6bcb2
backtrace:
      #00 pc 0005fcb2  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (abort+166) (BuildId: 68663d64ac44a935374eee374ddf6c9d)
      #01 pc 00e4c8dc  /data/app/com.bilbord.plus.bilbord-0o-LBQ3J8mU0n-fQauoaWw==/base.apk!libmaps-mobile.so (offset 0x6540000)
      #02 pc 00e4c2d8  /data/app/com.bilbord.plus.bilbord-0o-LBQ3J8mU0n-fQauoaWw==/base.apk!libmaps-mobile.so (offset 0x6540000)
      #03 pc 00e4c11c  /data/app/com.bilbord.plus.bilbord-0o-LBQ3J8mU0n-fQauoaWw==/base.apk!libmaps-mobile.so (offset 0x6540000)
      #04 pc 01293980  /data/app/com.bilbord.plus.bilbord-0o-LBQ3J8mU0n-fQauoaWw==/base.apk!libmaps-mobile.so (offset 0x6540000)
      #05 pc 01294430  /data/app/com.bilbord.plus.bilbord-0o-LBQ3J8mU0n-fQauoaWw==/base.apk!libmaps-mobile.so (offset 0x6540000)
      #06 pc 01294a14  /data/app/com.bilbord.plus.bilbord-0o-LBQ3J8mU0n-fQauoaWw==/base.apk!libmaps-mobile.so (offset 0x6540000)
      #07 pc 00efe7ac  /data/app/com.bilbord.plus.bilbord-0o-LBQ3J8mU0n-fQauoaWw==/base.apk!libmaps-mobile.so (offset 0x6540000)
      #08 pc 00eff39c  /data/app/com.bilbord.plus.bilbord-0o-LBQ3J8mU0n-fQauoaWw==/base.apk!libmaps-mobile.so (offset 0x6540000)
      #09 pc 00c06b8c  /data/app/com.bilbord.plus.bilbord-0o-LBQ3J8mU0n-fQauoaWw==/base.apk!libmaps-mobile.so (offset 0x6540000)
      #10 pc 00c06b24  /data/app/com.bilbord.plus.bilbord-0o-LBQ3J8mU0n-fQauoaWw==/base.apk!libmaps-mobile.so (offset 0x6540000)
      #11 pc 00c060c0  /data/app/com.bilbord.plus.bilbord-0o-LBQ3J8mU0n-fQauoaWw==/base.apk!libmaps-mobile.so (offset 0x6540000)
      #12 pc 00bf18a4  /data/app/com.bilbord.plus.bilbord-0o-LBQ3J8mU0n-fQauoaWw==/base.apk!libmaps-mobile.so (offset 0x6540000)
      #13 pc 00c00214  /data/app/com.bilbord.plus.bilbord-0o-LBQ3J8mU0n-fQauoaWw==/base.apk!libmaps-mobile.so (offset 0x6540000) (Java_com_yandex_runtime_async_internal_Scheduler_run+28)
      #14 pc 000dc519  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline+40) (BuildId: ed364b51d6bb80891e65519216d6b1c8)
      #15 pc 0201fcdd  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (com.yandex.runtime.async.internal.Scheduler.handleMessage+92)
      #16 pc 0201fe07  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage+134)
      #17 pc 02078a5b  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (android.os.Looper.loop+1114)
      #18 pc 000d7c0f  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_osr_stub+46) (BuildId: ed364b51d6bb80891e65519216d6b1c8)
      #19 pc 002587c5  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::jit::Jit::MaybeDoOnStackReplacement(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, unsigned int, int, art::JValue*)+1160) (BuildId: ed364b51d6bb80891e65519216d6b1c8)
      #20 pc 00432b57  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (MterpMaybeDoOnStackReplacement+134) (BuildId: ed364b51d6bb80891e65519216d6b1c8)
      #21 pc 000d73f4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (MterpHelpers+244) (BuildId: ed364b51d6bb80891e65519216d6b1c8)
      #22 pc 0039b98c  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.os.Looper.loop+1076)
      #23 pc 0042c451  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+932) (BuildId: ed364b51d6bb80891e65519216d6b1c8)
      #24 pc 000d2994  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static+20) (BuildId: ed364b51d6bb80891e65519216d6b1c8)
      #25 pc 001a7b8c  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.ActivityThread.main+208)
      #26 pc 001ecbfb  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEbb.llvm.521985996776985852+194) (BuildId: ed364b51d6bb80891e65519216d6b1c8)
      #27 pc 001f126d  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*)+120) (BuildId: ed364b51d6bb80891e65519216d6b1c8)
      #28 pc 0041e56d  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+832) (BuildId: ed364b51d6bb80891e65519216d6b1c8)
      #29 pc 000dc5a1  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+32) (BuildId: ed364b51d6bb80891e65519216d6b1c8)
      #30 pc 000d7bc5  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68) (BuildId: ed364b51d6bb80891e65519216d6b1c8)
      #31 pc 00434b2b  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+246) (BuildId: ed364b51d6bb80891e65519216d6b1c8)
      #32 pc 000dffb7  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+186) (BuildId: ed364b51d6bb80891e65519216d6b1c8)
      #33 pc 003751fb  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+54) (BuildId: ed364b51d6bb80891e65519216d6b1c8)
      #34 pc 003764df  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeMethod(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobject*, unsigned int)+798) (BuildId: ed364b51d6bb80891e65519216d6b1c8)
      #35 pc 0031ffcf  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::Method_invoke(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*)+30) (BuildId: ed364b51d6bb80891e65519216d6b1c8)
      #36 pc 000bc86f  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (art_jni_trampoline+110) (BuildId: 8b6cd5d1d735a5ecea2ce73e111ee29f4bf27cd6)
      #37 pc 000d7bc5  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68) (BuildId: ed364b51d6bb80891e65519216d6b1c8)
      #38 pc 00434a17  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+250) (BuildId: ed364b51d6bb80891e65519216d6b1c8)
      #39 pc 000dffa3  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+166) (BuildId: ed364b51d6bb80891e65519216d6b1c8)
      #40 pc 00210797  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+274) (BuildId: ed364b51d6bb80891e65519216d6b1c8)
      #41 pc 0020c90f  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+802) (BuildId: ed364b51d6bb80891e65519216d6b1c8)
      #42 pc 00429bcd  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+584) (BuildId: ed364b51d6bb80891e65519216d6b1c8)
      #43 pc 000d2814  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: ed364b51d6bb80891e65519216d6b1c8)
      #44 pc 0048e21a  /system/framework/framework.jar (com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run+22)
      #45 pc 001ecbfb  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEbb.llvm.521985996776985852+194) (BuildId: ed364b51d6bb80891e65519216d6b1c8)
      #46 pc 001f126d  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*)+120) (BuildId: ed364b51d6bb80891e65519216d6b1c8)
      #47 pc 0041e56d  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+832) (BuildId: ed364b51d6bb80891e65519216d6b1c8)
      #48 pc 000dc5a1  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+32) (BuildId: ed364b51d6bb80891e65519216d6b1c8)
      #49 pc 0083e961  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main+2624) (BuildId: 4715203b9e45ebc9cb938eb2cc784d6fb0d09854)
      #50 pc 000d7bc5  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68) (BuildId: ed364b51d6bb80891e65519216d6b1c8)
      #51 pc 00434b2b  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+246) (BuildId: ed364b51d6bb80891e65519216d6b1c8)
      #52 pc 000dffb7  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+186) (BuildId: ed364b51d6bb80891e65519216d6b1c8)
      #53 pc 003751fb  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+54) (BuildId: ed364b51d6bb80891e65519216d6b1c8)
      #54 pc 0037502d  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeWithVarArgs(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+288) (BuildId: ed364b51d6bb80891e65519216d6b1c8)
      #55 pc 002bcf27  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::JNI::CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+450) (BuildId: ed364b51d6bb80891e65519216d6b1c8)
      #56 pc 000a3355  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethod(_jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...)+28) (BuildId: 13bebefab0b9ce92186765028bf880b6)
      #57 pc 000a5923  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, android::Vector<android::String8> const&, bool)+506) (BuildId: 13bebefab0b9ce92186765028bf880b6)
      #58 pc 000022f5  /system/bin/app_process32 (main+688) (BuildId: d4953d8a8590b8a7c5546cc79cd4f267)
      #59 pc 0005a117  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__libc_init+66) (BuildId: 68663d64ac44a935374eee374ddf6c9d)
      #60 pc 0000202f  /system/bin/app_process32 (_start_main+38) (BuildId: d4953d8a8590b8a7c5546cc79cd4f267)
      #61 pc 00004456  <anonymous:ea5aa000>
Lost connection to device.
```

Comment: I really don't know if this helps, but I faced this random crashing code with weird fault addr. kills, and after a very long time of trying to understand, I found out that the issue disappears if I remove all break points from the debugger which I was running. I hope this helps, but I'm not sure.

Comment: the problem is I dont have any :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by replacing `sliding_up_panel` lib with native `DraggableScrollableSheet`